# Assign jquery variable to php variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to assign JQuery variable to the PHP variable. Any idea kindly

```
<?php    
  $phpvariable = jqueryvariable;    
?>
```

Comment: can't be done. because one runs at server and other is on browser. what you can do is either post a form or use ajax.

Comment: @jai any other idea i get jquery variable on click function

Comment: You should explain your problem, and why do you want to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The restriction is that you are assigning a value from frontend to backend and this can't be done because php runs at server side while js/jquery runs in the browser.

If you are using ajax then you can use the posted value as:

```
<?php

$phpvariable = $_REQUEST['jqueryvariable'];

?>
```

Assume this is the posted data in the ajax:

```
data:{ jqueryvariable:"theDummyVar" }
```

or without ajax:

use a `<input type="hidden" name="jqueryvariable" value="theDummyVar" />` and post it to the php. This needs to be in the form element.

Comment: then you can use form to submit the values. @WaqasKhan

Comment: and you can use `[type="hidden"]` if you are having some value which you don't want to show your user, otherwise you can use your normal input textfields.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to refer a jquery variable into phpvar? 
You can just pass the jquery variable via ajax post or you can do it this way.

```
<?php
$phpvariable = $_POST['textfieldId'];
?>
```

Comment: i think it should be textfieldname not ID

Comment: If you are not using Ajax the code above should work. As per Jai, you cannot directly relate the variables of front-end to backend.

Comment: @n00bster perhaps you want to change this `()` to `[]`.